# Issue with background-size:100% on blackberry

Tags: html, css, mobile, blackberry, device

i am using the following code to set the background image of the "logo" in h1 tag to the logo.

```
h1#logo {
margin: 5px 0 0 0px;
background: transparent url(../../assets/images/applewood_logo.png) no-repeat;
height:150px;
display:block;
cursor:pointer;
color: #ccc;
text-indent:-1900px;
max-width:145px;
background-size:100%;
z-index:500;
```

}

It works perfectly on all devices except blackberry where the edge of the logo is cut off. Here is a link to the site: http://www.applewoodindependent.co.uk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used to **css3-media-queries**

**Add to this css**

```
@media only screen and (min-width:50px) and (max-width:480px) {
    h1#logo{
        background-size: auto 81px;
    }

}
```

***[More info](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries)***

Comment: I thought blackberry devices dont support background-size? http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/27290/Overview_function_1176567_11.jsp